# Intercept all accesses to a column in Postgres

Tags: postgresql

I have a table (several tables, actually) which contains a textual `item_id` column, originally populated with an ID provided by a third-party data source. Unfortunately, the data source recently changed the format of their IDs. Meanwhile, my customers will call into my service using whatever format of the ID they most recently saw, meaning that they frequently get incomplete data because they're looking at an `item_id` which is either too old or too new.

Fortunately, the change in format was relatively straightforward, so it's easy for me to normalize both old and new `item_id` values into a consistent value, but I'd like to do this for ALL queries regardless of where they come from. Is it possible to set up some sort of trigger that intercepts any query against the `item_id` column and normalizes the queried value?

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for a VIEW

Comment: Maybe `RULE` will help? (Never used them). [link](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/static/rules.html)

Comment: Using a VIEW might work, but I'd have to create a view for each affected table and change the application's DB layer to redirect queries to the view rather than the underlying table. Possibly error prone. I'm reading the RULE docs now to see if that will help.